# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '[Table_id]'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '[Table_id]' when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

Seems very simple yet I'm having major issues with this.
I'm using Entity Framework 6 and having problems associating one object to another. In my application I want to add a new Person record with a new, connected Address, that's associated with an existing address type ( "mailing", "personal", etc)
Assigning a new Address record with an existing AddressType to a resident for example.

```
var person = new Person();
var address = new Address();

address.AddressType = _systemService.GetAddressType(addressTypeId); 
person.Addresses.Add(address);
_personService.SavePerson(person);
```

Committing changes to the DBContext in SavePerson() throws an error that:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AddressTypes'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AddressTypes'.

This should be so simple yet it doesn't work. Let me show you some guts of how I'm retrieving the `AddressType` and how I'm saving the `Person` though:

```
    public AddressType GetAddressType(Guid id)
    {
        var addressType = _repositoryContainer.AddressType.Get(id);
        return addressType;
    }

    public Person SavePerson(Person person)
    {            
      _repositoryContainer.Person.Add(person);
      _repositoryContainer.CommitChanges();
       return person;
    }
```

And as far as DBContext goes I'm passing the same one to a single Repository container, that's then used by the application for all DB operations. :

```
 public class RepositoryContainer : IRepositoryContainer
    {
        private readonly MyDBContext _dbContext;

        public RepositoryContainer(MyDBContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            //initiating repositories here
            .
            .
        }
     {
```

How can I add a new person to my application with an Address, that has an existing Address type ? I've done it many times but not sure why the problem comes up in this simple scenario.

Comment: Your `GetAddressType()` method returns an existing record. You cannot add that same record to the db. You clear what you wanting to do, but if your wanting to save a `Person` with an existing `AddressType`, then set the appropriate property in `Person` and save that, not add the `AddressType`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm a bit confused with what you said. Partly because I'm used to Nhibernate doing a great job at recognizing existing "Sessions" and allowing me to connect them to new Object instances. 
How do I associate an existing Type to a new Object in EF and my scenario then ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what your wanting to do. Showing your models might make it clearer

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to add a new Person record, with a new address but address is going to be of an existing type ( "mailing", "personal", etc )

Comment: An new address or an existing address (the last paragraph of the question states _associate it with an **existing** Address_)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I corrected the sentence. New person, new address-> existing address type. Do you have a suggestion Stephen ?

Answer (score 0):

hmmm how about this line:

```
#original
person.Addresses.Add(Address);
```

shouldn't it look like this?:

```
#my
person.Addresses.Add(address);
```

The difference is A in address filed. Original refers to a type. My to a variable name. Generaly not a good idea to have the same var name as an object type. But maybe its not it...

Comment: Yes, I think it's an obvious typo in my example above.

Comment: No, this is not the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You asked: "How can I add a new person to my application with an Address, that has an existing Address type ? " the answer is: person.Addresses.Add(address);

The error that you got 
`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AddressTypes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AddressTypes'.`
Is because calling person.Addresses.Add(Address); creates an address with id null/0 (we need to see your mysql schema to be sure) and since you run it more than once you cant insert duplicate key. it is because entity framework auto creates objects(Address) that are attached to entities(person) and tries to insert them to DB when you add a person. Using address instead of Address passes the existing id and insert will not happen.